# Change UILabel.frame when orientation changes using viewWillTransition

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uibutton

I programmatically create a set of buttons in the viewDidLoad() of my UIInputViewController. I am trying to change the size of these buttons when the orientation changes from landscape to portrait and vice-versa.

I am trying to do this by using

```
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator)
```

but when I go through the same code I used to create my buttons in viewDidLoad() with only the UIlabel.frame change to accommodate the new height and width, the view is not updated. Do I have to first remove the buttons and load them from scratch or is there another method to do this?

Below is the full code from the function.

```
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)
    let width = screensize.width
    var height = CGFloat(141)
    let sizey = screensize.height

    switch sizey {
    case 1366:
        height = CGFloat(383-15)
    case 1112:
        height = CGFloat(320-15)
    case 812:
        height = CGFloat(141-15)
    case 1024:
        height = CGFloat(320-15)
    case 736:
        height = CGFloat(226-15)
    case 667:
        height = CGFloat(216-15)
    case 568:
        height = CGFloat(216-15)
    case 768:
        height = CGFloat(420-15)
    default:
        height = CGFloat(141-15)
    }

    connection.frame = CGRect(x: 0,         y: 0, width: width/2,     height: 15)
    serialNum.frame = CGRect( x: width/2,   y: 0, width: width/2,     height:15)

    plus.frame = CGRect(x:0,              y: 15,            width: width/5,height: height/4)
    minus.frame = CGRect(x:0,             y: height/4+15,   width: width/5,height: height/4)
    left.frame = CGRect(x:0,              y: height/2+15,   width: width/5,height: height/4)
    nextKeyboardButton.frame = CGRect(x:0,y: 3*height/4+15, width: width/5,height: height/4)

    num1.frame = CGRect(x:width/5,    y: 15,            width: width/5,height: height/4)
    num4.frame = CGRect(x:width/5,    y: height/4+15,   width: width/5,height: height/4)
    num7.frame = CGRect(x:width/5,    y: height/2+15,   width: width/5,height: height/4)
    comma.frame = CGRect(x:width/5,   y: 3*height/4+15, width: width/5,height: height/4)

    num2.frame = CGRect(x:width*2/5,y: 15,            width: width/5,height: height/4)
    num5.frame = CGRect(x:width*2/5,y: height/4+15,   width: width/5,height: height/4)
    num8.frame = CGRect(x:width*2/5,y: height/2+15,   width: width/5,height: height/4)
    num0.frame = CGRect(x:width*2/5,y: 3*height/4+15, width: width/5,height: height/4)


    num3.frame = CGRect(x:width*3/5,y: 15,            width: width/5,height: height/4)
    num6.frame = CGRect(x:width*3/5,y: height/4+15,   width: width/5,height: height/4)
    num9.frame = CGRect(x:width*3/5,y: height/2+15,   width: width/5,height: height/4)
    period.frame = CGRect(x:width*3/5,y: 3*height/4+15, width: width/5,height: height/4)

    back.frame = CGRect(x:width*4/5,      y: 15,            width: width/5,  height: height/4)
    spaceBar.frame = CGRect(x: width*4/5, y: height/4+15,   width: width/5,  height: height/4)
    right.frame =
        CGRect(x: width*4/5,    y: height/2+15,   width: width/5,  height: height/4)
    returnKey.frame = CGRect(x:width*4/5, y: height*3/4+15, width: width/5,  height: height/4)


    self.view.addSubview(spaceBar)
    self.view.addSubview(num1)
    self.view.addSubview(num2)
    self.view.addSubview(num3)
    self.view.addSubview(num4)
    self.view.addSubview(num5)
    self.view.addSubview(num6)
    self.view.addSubview(num7)
    self.view.addSubview(num8)
    self.view.addSubview(num9)
    self.view.addSubview(num0)
    self.view.addSubview(plus)
    self.view.addSubview(minus)
    self.view.addSubview(back)
    self.view.addSubview(left)
    self.view.addSubview(right)
    self.view.addSubview(period)
    self.view.addSubview(comma)
    self.view.addSubview(nextKeyboardButton)
    self.view.addSubview(returnKey)
```

Comment: Why don't you go with autolayout

Comment: @Sh_Khan How do I use auto layout in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the ‘size’ argument that you get in the ‘viewWillTransition’ method to set the new ‘width’ and ‘sizey’ properties in stead of ‘screensize’.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't call `addSubview` on orientation change if you've already added the buttons in `viewDidLoad`. Updating the frame should be enough.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have added these set of buttons in the `viewDidLoad()` of your `UIInputViewController`, you don't need to use `addSubview` in `viewWillTransition to size` method.

**Even after rotating the device still you are using the old screen size.**

Change

```
let width = screensize.width
let sizey = screensize.height
```

To

```
let width = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
let sizey = UIScreen.main.bounds.height
```

Or

```
let width = size.width
let sizey = size.height
```

Comment: I am not using the full screen size. This code is for a custom keyboard extension and I am using the size of the keyboard rectangle and my width and height. I am adjusting the height based off of the total size of the screen (you can see this in my switch case statements.)

Comment: @MWaz In viewWillTransition to size method you have used screenSize variable. And changed all label, button frame based on this size. But you've not changed this screenSize anywhere. If it was (100,150) in portrait, then it is (100,150) in landscape also. Hope you understand